# Flutter audio from earpiece on ios while speech to text is initialized

Tags: ios, flutter, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech-to-text

On my app on ios, I am using [flutter tts](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tts) for audio output and [speech to text](https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text) for input. Only if STT is initialized the volume is very low because the audio is coming from the earpiece and not from the speaker.

I have already tried different categories [Flutter text to speech low volume on ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64501325/flutter-text-to-speech-low-volume-on-ios). But nothings has changed.

On android I could not test it yet because I have not figured out why I can not initialize STT.

My code:

```
final FlutterTts tts = FlutterTts();
final SpeechToText stt = SpeechToText();

void onInit() {
  Wakelock.enable().then((_) async => print(await Wakelock.enabled)); //keep the device screen awake
  initTts();
  initStt();
}

void initTts() async {
  await tts.setLanguage("de-DE");
  await tts.setVolume(1.0);

  await tts.setIosAudioCategory(IosTextToSpeechAudioCategory.playAndRecord, [
    IosTextToSpeechAudioCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers
  ]);

  speakWelcomeText();
}

void initStt() async {
  await stt.initialize(
    onStatus: (val) => print('[stt] onStatus: $val'),
    onError: (val) => print('[stt] onError: $val'),
  );
}
`
``
```

Comment: Have you found a fix?

Comment: Still seeking a fix...

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to call:

```
    await flutterTts.setIosAudioCategory(
      IosTextToSpeechAudioCategory.playAndRecord,
      [IosTextToSpeechAudioCategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker],
    );
```

Before every

```
    await flutterTts.speak(text);
```

This seems to do the trick!